# Newly inserted documents to RavenDb not showing up in searches

Tags: ravendb

I have a standard install of RavenDb and am running into some problems after I insert a new document.

If I do a subsequent search or try to pull that document by it's `Id` after I've inserted it there is about a 25% chance that it's not included in the search results or that I get an error trying to retrieve it by it's `Id`. When I open up Raven Studio I can see that the document exists so what's the deal?

Is this because whatever index it is using to find the document hasn't been updated yet? How can I ensure that I am always querying the latest data so that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it looks like this is due to stale indexes. There is a way to check if there are pending index operations which you can use as a way of ensuring that you are querying the latest data. This article describes how to do that:

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/stale-indexes